# Get array from PHP to AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to retrieve a set of array from PHP to ajax. The code I have does not return anything back, could someone help me how to retrieve the value from PHP to ajax. If i dont create the array in the mysql_fetch it will retrieve the last value from the database and pass it to the ajax function. I want to get the whole values. How can i do this?

AJAX CODE:

```
<script>
  //Global Variables
  var channel;
 function overall(){
    $(".one").show();
    $(".two").hide();
    $(".three").hide();
    $(".four").hide();
    window['channel']="overall";
     $.ajax({
             type:"GET",
             url:"dash2.php",
             data:{channel:channel},
             dataType:'json',
             success:function(data){
                    console.log(data.a);
                    console.log(data.b);
                    console.log(data.c);
                    }
            });
    }
</script>
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
   error_reporting(0);
   $channel=$_GET['channel'];
    $host="192.168.0.29";
    $username="root";
    $password="root";
    $dbname="realcl";
  mysql_connect($host,$username,$password)
    OR DIE ('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.');
    mysql_select_db($dbname);
    $query = 'select * from '.$channel;
    $masterresult = mysql_query($query);
    $success[];
    $timeout[];
    $fail[];

    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($masterresult))
    {
        $success[]=$row1[1];
        $timeout[]=$row1[2];
        $fail[]=$row1[3]; 
    }

    echo json_encode(array("a"=>$success,"b"=>$timeout,"c"=>$fail));
?>
```

Comment: @undefined This is an exact duplicate

Comment: this question is regarding the usage of array in ajax not resolving the issue of type

Comment: What happens when someone enters `channel` as `dual where 0; drop database realcl;--`

Answer (score 0):

This will lead to a fatal error (and because of that, non-valid json...):

```
$success[];
$timeout[];
$fail[];
```

You probably want:

```
$success = array();
// etc.
```

And you have a huge sql injection problem, you should check your table name against a white-list of allowed table names. You should also switch to PDO (or mysqli) as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Comment: iknow it will give me an error :(  could you help me modify the ajax to recieve multiple values

Comment: @jibindcruz Just change it like I specified in my answer.

Comment: see this is for the php part right? how would i change it for the ajax?